# Empty RSS results

Tags: php, xml, rss

Why this code results empty in my hosting, but works well in my local?

```
$raw = file_get_contents($rssURL); 
$xml = new SimpleXmlElement($raw);

echo "<b>RSS Items:</b><br /><br />";
foreach($xml->channel->item as $item) {
    echo $item->title."</br >";
}
```

`libxml` version: 2.6.32; `libxml2` version: 2.6.32

I also tried this code:

```
# INSTANTIATE CURL.
$curl = curl_init();

# CURL SETTINGS.
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $rssURL);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);  
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);  

# GRAB THE XML FILE.
$xml = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);

# SET UP XML OBJECT.
$xmlObj = simplexml_load_string($xml);

echo "<b>RSS Items:</b><br /><br />";
foreach($xmlObj->channel->item as $item) {
    echo $item->title."</br >";
}

echo "<br /><b>var_dump:</b><br><br>";
var_dump(libxml_get_errors())
```

The result was `array(0) { }`

Is there any differences between coding this snippet for Windows and Linux (I don't think so)?

Any Idea's?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.libxml-get-errors.php and find out what errors simplexml_load_string() is throwing since it returns false on error.

Also, your provider might not let you make outside calls from your software, just a thought.

Comment: Does curl_exec() throw an error?  Also, what is the value of $xml?

Answer (score 0):

I use godaddy and I have to put in a proxy to make outbound calls.

```
curl_setopt ($curl,CURLOPT_PROXY,'http://proxy.shr.secureserver.net:3128');
```